# Extracting a value from an HTML tag attribute in Java

Tags: java, regex

I have recently taken on a community challenge and I am trying to extract the value of the 'rel' tag in the following line:

`<td><a title='Visit Personal Stats Page for ijackk' href='personal.php?name=ijackk&amp;clan=ph_chat_ftw' class='rsn' rel='ijackk' style='color: #FFFFFF;'>ijackk</a></td>`

The reason for this is the challenge requires me to extract the names of multiple users off of a memberlist (a list of peoples with attributes relating to their account).  I don't *HAVE* to use regular expressions but I feel that it would be the best.  I have seen the classic post of why regular expressions are bad but I have also seen posts saying using it for stuff similar to this isn't a bad thing.

The following is what I have done thus far:

```
public class Parser {

public static void main(String[] arguments) {
    new Parser().parse();
}

public void parse() {
    try {
        URL url = new URL("http://www.runehead.com/clans/ml.php?clan=ph_chat_ftw");
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
        String line;
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            if (line.contains("Visit")) {
                stringBuilder.append(line).append("\n");
                System.out.println(line);
            }
        }
        Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("\\?rel='([A-Za-z0-9_]*)'").matcher(stringBuilder.toString());
        while (matcher.find()) {
            System.out.println("matched: " + matcher.group(1));
        }
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

}
```

The output of what I have there is what I have provided above, except for every name.  The matcher does not find anything, though.  Could I get some help please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're assuming that the `rel` attribute immediately follows the `?`, but this isn't necessarily the case. You could use the following:

```
Pattern.compile("rel=\"([A-Za-z0-9_]*)\"")
```

That certainly works, but as others have said, you're better off using a proper HTML parser. Here's a [jsoup](http://jsoup.org/) example:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect(
    "http://www.runehead.com/clans/ml.php?clan=ph_chat_ftw").get();
Elements users = doc.select("a[rel]");
for (Element user : users) {
    System.out.println(user.attr("rel"));
}
```

That's much cleaner (and safer (and more flexible (and maintainable))) than your regex approach.

Answer (score 2):

Use a proper HTML parsing library. I prefer [jSoup](http://jSoup.org), but there are many others.

Using RegEx to parse HTML is much more pain than it's worth in most cases. Not only is it hard to do in the first place, but anything you come up with that *does* work will likely be *so* convoluted that it will essentially be completely unmaintainable.

---

[Here's an example](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/attributes-text-html) using jSoup to get the `rel` attribute:

```
String html = "<p>An <a href='http://example.com/' rel='someValue'><b>example</b></a> link.</p>";
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
Element link = doc.select("a").first();

String text = doc.body().text(); // "An example link"
String linkRel = link.attr("rel"); // "someValue"
```

Comment: I was looking into that library earlier and couldn't find any implementation for what I was looking for.  Could you be so kind as to give an example?  I'd appreciate it.

Comment: Thank you for the example.  When I use it, it works great!  The only problem is that it's printing like this: `Sanyboi
Sanyboi shes my hope
Sanyboi shes my hope raeiden
Sanyboi shes my hope raeiden E1itez
Sanyboi shes my hope raeiden E1itez krunal930` the whole way through the document.  Any way to print them one by one (or to put them into an ArrayList, each index having a name)?  Edit: nevermind I was doing it while reading the data This is excellent, thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

Regex and HTML combined are swear words around here. Regular expressions aren't great at parsing non-regular markup like HTML or XML.

You'd probably be better using an HTML parser library to do this. Someone seems to have done just that here, in the aptly named [HTML Parser library](http://htmlparser.sourceforge.net).

EDIT:- Or jSoup might work too. There's plenty of choice out there!

Comment: Thank you for your contribution!